# redirect while templating page

Tags: python, html, web, flask

In Flask, how do you redirect to a different page while rendering a template?

```
@app.route('/foo.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    if request.method == "POST":
        x = request.form['x']
        y = request.form['y']
        if x > y:
            return redirect(render_template("bar.html", title="Bar"))
        else:
            return render_template("foo.html", title="Foo")

    return render_template("foo.html", title="Foo")


@app.route('/bar.html')
def bar():
    return render_template("bar.html", title="Bar")
```

`return redirect(render_template("bar.html", title="Bar"))` causes the full page that would be templated and displayed to instead appear in the URL:

`http://localhost:5000/<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Bar</title></head>...`

This results in a 404 error because this page doesn't exist.

I've tried `redirect(url_for('bar'))` but I need to pass Jinja2 variables to url_for and have it template the page.

Answer (score 2):

For redirecting you want a URL

```
return redirect(url_for('bar'))
```

You'll need to import `url_for` from Flask. If you need to pass additional variables you should put them in as parameters

```
somevalue = 1
return redirect(url_for('bar', somevar=somevalue) )
```

then

```
@app.route('/bar/<somevar>')
def bar(somevar):
    # do something with somevar probably
    return render_template("bar.html", title="Bar")
```

Comment: I need to pass Jinja2 variables that will be templated in bar.html, 

eg. replace `<title>{{ title }}</title>` with `<title>Bar</title>`

Your suggested approach does not work.

Comment: Yes of course it does. Pass your title as a variable, or pass a variable that tells it what title to set. Redirecting generates a 301 or 302 code the browser, you aren't returning a template at all.